# git checkout |TUTORIAL_JAVA_VERSION|

Tags: java, git

I am following a tutorial to build an application based on Kurento (WebRTC media Server). Somewhere it is written:

```
 git clone https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-java.git
 cd kurento-tutorial-java/kurento-hello-world
 git checkout |TUTORIAL_JAVA_VERSION|
```

How do I know TUTORIAL_JAVA_VERSION in the last line of code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [tutorial-1-helloworld.html](http://www.kurento.org/docs/current/tutorials/java/tutorial-1-helloworld.html) you should use `6.1.0` (`6.1.0` beeing a git `tag`):

```
git clone https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-java.git
cd kurento-tutorial-java/kurento-hello-world
git checkout 6.1.0
mvn compile exec:java
```

Answer (score 1):

TUTORIAL_JAVA_VERSION would be the name of a branch or tag that you've pulled down from the Git repo.

Looking at the repo in Github, there's no branch or tag called this.

I'd contact whoever created the tutorial and ask what branch / tag you should be using.